# iPad specific code within CSS

Tags: css, ipad, indentation

I am trying to typeset text like a screenplay.
I am using the following code for this [website](http://story-architect.com/?p=1614).

```
<style type="text/css">
.header {
font-family: courier new, monospace;
color: #999999;
font-size: 12pt;
line-height: 12pt;
width: 38.25em;
}
.character {  
font-family: courier new, monospace;  
color: #999999;
font-size: 12pt;
line-height: 12pt;
padding-left: 12.5em;
width: 21em;
}

[etc]
```

I noticed that the iPad does not display indented text (padding) the same way as safari on my desktop does. There's a discrepancy of about 0.5em. Is there a way to have indentation universally apply the desktop, iPad, and iPhone? Is there a way to target specific sections of the above CSS for the iPad only?

Comment: I think the problem lie elsewhere, maybe it's the width being defined as em or the font size being defined as pt.. anyway my point is I did not have this issue defining stuff in px/em/%

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use media queries to determine when the viewer is using a display that has the screen size of the ipad, or any other device with a similar size.

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 768px) {
  // insert css specific to ipad portrait
}

@media all and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  // insert css specific to iphone landscape
}

@media all and (max-device-width: 320px) {
  // insert css specific to iphone portrait
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I am not an expert in this field. Can you show me how the code looks when embedded in the CSS or website for that matter?

Comment: Also, what happens if I use an iPad 4 with a screen resolution similar to a desktop?

Comment: The iPad 4 has a higher screen resolution which effects images but not the size of the browser window. So, it will be the same as all other ipads. The best way to see an example of this in action is to look at a site like [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/) and rescale the browser window. Also, if you are satisfied with this answer, click on the up vote arrow and mark as answered.

Comment: Some more info: I'm using a monospaced font. For instance, the dialogue in the screenplay should be indented by exactly 10 characters. I can make it work for the desktop, but not the iPad/iPhone...

Comment: Now you are moving away from your original question and you should maybe start a new thread. However, you can use the [text-indent](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp) property in css to indent the first line a certain amount of space.

Comment: Somehow the text @media is displayed on the website when I try to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above, you can include something like http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

which allows you to apply specific rules based on what mobile/OS/etc is being sniffed out and just listing the correct class

you can apply specific rules for whatever you need for e.g.

```
.ipad #div1 {
/* rules here */
}

.iphone #div2 {
/* rules here*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need different css codes/packages for the iPad, depending on the element of the screenplay. I would need something like: .ipad #div1, .ipad2 #div2, etc.