# Trying to make my site responsive

Tags: css

I am using the following css code. What I want to do is if the user is on a iPad I want the background-image to be headerold.jpg or some way to make the current headernew.jpg to display properly on the iPad. Currently part of each end is cut off. I have tried @media query but I am not able to get the code to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Roger

```
div.art-header-jpeg
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:-50%;
width: 1344px;
height: 150px;
background-image: url('../img/headernew.jpg');
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {background-image: url('../img/headerold.jpg');}
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: We need to see the full @media query in order to tell you if there's something wrong with it.

Comment: This could help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790751/ipad-specific-code-within-css

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

CSS:

```
 img.bg {
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to a particular image (change accordingly*/
  img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
  }
}
```

However there are different methods including a JQuery Method. You should check out some discussion about it [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to get the headernew.jpg to display on an iPad properly as well as other computer screens but first just the iPad. If I remove the position: absolute then the complete header moves to the right and only shows about 50% of the header. Is there something I need to add like suggested in another post like this ..

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

if so where should it be placed?

My code now looks like this;

```
 div.art-header-jpeg
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:-50%;
width: 1344px;
height: 150px;
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) { 
div.art-header-jpeg 
background-image: url('../img/headernew.jpg');
}
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}
```